# Yaml-schema is throwing incorrect error message

Tags: yaml, serverless, aws-serverless

I am getting the error `String is longer than the maximum length of 1.yaml-schema: AWSDynamoDBTableAttributeDefinition`  for the block of code below

```
TodosTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: Todos-${self:provider.stage}
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: todoId
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: createdAt
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: name
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: dueDate
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: todoId
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: createdAt
        KeyType: RANGE
    BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
    StreamSpecification:
      StreamViewType: NEW_IMAGE
    LocalSecondaryIndexes:
      - IndexName: todoNameIndex
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: todoId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: name
            KeyType: RANGE
        Projection:
          ProjectionType: ALL
```

Interpretation: the yaml schema seems to be confusing the `AttributeName` with `AttributeType`. As it expects the string to be only one character.

How is this fixed?

Comment: Ignore the issue. It is a faulty type check